# Hide and show Navigation bar using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a litte Navigation Bar on the left side of my page. you have MainNavigation bulletpoints on the left side of it and then to the right when you klick one of the points you have a list with links to subpages. 
I added a little Button on the right side of the navigation Bar so I can close it and give more space for the actual content.

Now comes the tricky part. I want that when the menu is closed the main navigation items do not refresh the page or go to any link. they should just open then right menu again.

Cant supply the whole code here is a Idea of what i did

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hideButton").click(function() {
    $("#sidebar-content").toggle("slide");
  });
});
```

```css
.leftnavigation {
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
}

.icon-bar div {
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation" class="leftnavigation">
  <div class="icon-bar" style="float: left; height: 100%; background-color: #2D4400">
    <div>Test</div>
  </div>
  <div id='sidebar-content' style="float:left; width: 215px; background-color: #385400; height: 100%;">
    <a id="hideButton"></a>
    <li><a>Test</a></li>
  </div>

</div>
```

Instead of the `<a>` tags i use the `<p:link>` tag from Primefaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it

```js
(function(){
  var buttonList = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
  for(var index = 0; index < buttonList.length; index++) {
    buttonList[index].addEventListener("click", function(event){
      var nav = document.getElementById("sidebar-content");
      if(nav.classList.contains("open")) nav.classList.remove("open");
      else nav.classList.add("open");
    });
  }
})();
```

```css
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#sidebar-content {
  background-color: #385400;
  transition: all 1.2s; 
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 0;
}

#sidebar-content.open {
  width: 215px;
}

.icon-bar {
  background-color: #2D4400;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.icon-bar>div {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
}

.toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="icon-bar">
    <div class="toggle">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar-content">
    <a id="hideButton"></a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>Test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is nice and I already did something liek this but only the light green part should be toggled and then when you click on "test"(which would normaly take you to the main Page of that menu) it should toggle again.

Comment: @Frekell So the dark green part should always be visible?

Comment: yes exactly. Sorry that i did not made this clear in my post.

Comment: Yes that is kinda what I want and it helped me with the Idea what I want to do now. thanks for helping.

Comment: @Frekell why kinda? is there anything missing?

Comment: As i said i wanted that it opens when i klick the "test" link. But without that it refreshes the page.

Comment: @Frekell which of the two test links?

Comment: the one in the dark green field.

Comment: @Frekell Is this better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144446/discussion-between-frekell-and-nick-zoum).